# Creating SEO friendly URLs with htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite

when I change the link It shows me an error page. maybe there is a problem with my website what do you think?
There is the url in my website: www.mywebsite.com/picture.php?1
and I want to change it to something like this: www.mywebsite.com/picture/1

here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^website.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteRule ^contact\/?$ contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^terms\/?$ terms.php [L]

**RewriteRule ^picture/(.*)/$ picture.php?$1 [L]**
```

Please help,
I have no clue what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
<base href="www.mywebsite.com" />
```

At the top of your page, this might work.

EDIT:

Try using this rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule picture/(.*)/$ /picture.php?$1 [L, NC]
```

Comment: @YarikSkovorodko, try using the rewrite rule I have just edited into my post.

Comment: It is now doing the Internal Server Error

Comment: Given your comment from below, how does it know what ID is equal to? Surely in your URL it should be `www.mywebsite.com/picture.php?id=1` nor just `...php?1`

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the first part of your htaccess works, replace your last line with the following:

```
   RewriteRule ^picture/(.*)$ /picture.php?$1 [NC]
```

Comment: now it give me an error from my script. Here is a code from my script : mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE id = $id") or die("Picture doesn't exist.") looks like it cannot retrive the "id" from my database.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^picture/(.*)$ /picture.php?id=$1 [NC]`
and add `$id = $_GET['id'];` above your mysql statement